# Why is this version of the axiom schema of specification correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic

I am reading a book on logic and set theory in my spare time and also found [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification). In the article and the book, the axiom schema is given by

$$\forall w_1,...,w_n \forall A\exists B\forall x(x \in B \iff [x \in A \wedge \varphi(x,w_1,...,w_n,A)]).$$ However, this should not be a formula of FOL, since we write $\forall w_1,...,w_n$, where $n$ is some natural number. Why is this allowed, if this is not an FOL formula? Is this false and if so, is there a fix?

Comment: It's not a single formula, it's a *scheme*. Each formula $\varphi$ determines an instance of the scheme, and $n$ depends on $\varphi$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Okay, but why is this scheme allowed to be expressible in FOL? A sentence such as $\forall x_1,...,x_n (P(x_1,...,x_n))$ appears not to be allowed in FOL. Also I am not sure how $n$ depends on $\varphi$, and isn't $n$ free in this expression? How is this allowed?

Comment: No, $n$ is completely determined by $\varphi$ - it's the arity of $\varphi$ minus two. E.g. the separation axiom corresponding to the formula $$\varphi(s,t,u,v)\equiv s=t\wedge u=v$$ is $$\forall w_1,w_2\forall A\exists B\forall x(x\in B\iff [x\in A\wedge (x=w_1\wedge w_2=A)]).$$ As soon as you know what $\varphi$ is, you know what $n$ is.

Comment: @NoahSchweber But isn't this also the case for the example I mentioned above: $\forall x_1,...,x_n(P(x_1,...,x_n))$? If we know what $P$ is, we know what $n$ is. Why is this not allowed then?

Comment: It wasn't clear to me from what you wrote that $P$ was a predicate with a well-defined arity. If it is, then there's no real problem - the use of variable indexing and "$...$" is benign abuse of notation in this case.

Comment: "$\ldots$" and "$n$" here are not symbols in FOL.  The line stands for an infinite amount of FOL formulas that cannot be written down one by one.

Comment: For example, if you want to refer to a hypothetical list of axioms "$f(1) = 1$, $f(2) = 2$, $f(3) = 3$, ...", you cannot write down all of them one by one, so you would say something like "the axiom schema $f(n) = n$ where $n$ is a positive integer literal", but that doesn't mean "$n$" itself is a symbol in FOL.

Comment: @NoahSchweber So if $P$ is a any predicate, the formula $\forall x_1,...,x_n(P(x_1,...,x_n))$ is an FOL formula? In other words, for every $n$ and every $n$-ary predicate $P$ we have that this is an FOL formula? Also Can the abuse of notation you mention be avoided? I would like to know how, if that is the case, as I would like to be as formal as possible.

Comment: Studying mathematics via DFS is usually not a good idea, and an approach that combines BFS with a bit of DFS and some heuristic algorithm is better, since it can give you a broader understanding which you can then go back and fill in the gaps. My point is that fixating on something like this will often prevent you from properly understanding what is actually going on, and to some extent, it is better to blackbox this issue, put it aside, and get back to it once you've got a firmer grasp on logic and set theory.

Answer (score 0):

What we have to understand is that the [Axiom schema of specification (aka: separation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification#Statement) is a [schema](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/schema/), i.e. it is not a formula of the language but a recipe in the meta-language to describe an infinite collection of formulas that well be the instances of the schema.

Due to the fact that the schema is not a formula of the formal language, we can use a little bit of sloppiness in its formulation, because the meta-language is the "usual" mathematical jargon made of formulas and natural language (and abbreviations).

Thus, if adopt the usual convention [see [van Dalen](https://www.cin.ufpe.br/%7Emlogica/livros/Logic%20and%20Structure%20-%20Van%20Dalen.pdf), page 66] that

> a (meta-)expressions like $\varphi(x)$ stay for a formula of the language, but this neither means that the listed variable occurs free nor that no other ones occur free,

the meta-language specification of the axiom schema can be rephrased (avoiding dots and "indexes") as follows:

> for each formula $\varphi(x)$ in the language of set theory with free variable $x$, the *universal closure* of $\forall A\,\exists B\,\forall x\,(x\in B\Leftrightarrow [x\in A\land \varphi (x)])$ is an axiom.

*Nitpicking comment*: to be precise, the part "with free variable $x$" is *not* mandatory (can you see why?)

Comment: Thanks! I will have to think more about your question since I don't have an answer right now. Is it then also correct that statements such as $\forall x_1,...,x_n P(x_1,...,x_n)$ are also in a metalanguage? In theory such sentences should be possible to me, since they involve finitely many variables although we don't know how many when arguing about them. But nevertheless they are finite, so in every explicit case where $n$ is known they are sentences of FOL. Thus it should also be fine to reason about them with arbitrary $n$, but these then are parts of the metalanguage. Is that correct?