# What is the difference bwtween an axiom and an axiom schema

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm currently following a textbook on an introduction to first order logic; it's called The Logic Book (6th edition). I couldn't quite understand the clear distinction between an axiom and an axiom schema given by the definition provided in the textbook:[image]

Notice that it says axiom *schema* and not *scheme* for I have been informed that there was a clear difference between the two words. If anyone could be of help and educate me about the distinction between an axiom and an axiom schema, that would be of much help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @TankutBeygu no, not really; and I've already seen that post. Notice I said *schema* not *scheme*

Comment: *Schema* is the correct term to distinguish the technical sense from the ordinary senses of *scheme*. See the SEoP article [Schema](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/schema/).

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4554508/why-is-this-version-of-the-axiom-schema-of-specification-correct) for example.

Answer (score 1):

This is an axiom schema:
It is the second ZF axiom of set theory.

Called axiom schem of replacement.

$(\forall x)(\exists y)[x\in y \iff (\exists z)((x\in z) \land \phi(x))]$

what is special about it is that an infinite number of formulae can replace $\phi(x)$.

An axiom on the other hand has one formula only:

axiom of extensionality for example:

$(\forall x)(\forall A)(\forall B)(A=B\iff (x \in A \iff x\in B))$

Comment: So if I understood you correctly, an axiom schema is something like a formula template that you can use to generate an infinite number of axioms by replacing the metavariable in the axiom schema?

Comment: Indeed it is so.